# widgets missing from graphical layout palette (android on eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, palette

I'm not sure what happened exactly, but when I started up eclipse, there are no widgets in the graphical layout palette, as in the folders show nothing in them. It has worked before. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Though the answer was simple, the question seems valid. I was trying to figure out the same thing. Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 9):

Got the same problem, just enlarge your Graphical Layout and it works.

Comment: That's not a bug, its a hidden eclipse feature

Answer (score 2):

Switch your computer system language from your country language to English! The widget folders in palette cannot read your country language; only English.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem, where some of the widgets such as TextView and EditText were missing from the paleltte. 
Here is what I did - from the paleltte, click on the arrow pointing downwards and select "Refresh Preview", here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right click on palette then select DOCK ON then select left

Answer (score 0):

It will not show if there is not enough space on your screen fr some reason. You need to minimize a window to open up your working space and it will show.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me.

After trying everything, I **changed the theme** of the project. And oddly, the widgets reappeared.

The themes can be changed in the top bar of the design window.